# Spinner Index Android

Tags: android, indexing, spinner, android-adapter

I've a simple problem. I'm creating two spinner, in first spinner I want to select a categorie, and in the second spinner I want to select an element of this group. I have a good result for now, but with small problem.
If I select an item of second spinner, for example on index 4, if I change element of first spinner, the second spinner go to element on fourth index (if the fourth doesn't exist go to the last).

If I use spinner2.setSelection(0), I can't change value of second spinner.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make your question clear and add some code you have used

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> categoryList;
    private ArrayList<String> elementList;
    private Spinner categorySpinner,elementSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // add categoryList and element to list
        categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        elementList = new ArrayList<>();

        categoryList.add("Category 1");
        categoryList.add("Category 2");
        categoryList.add("Category 3");
        categoryList.add("Category 4");
        categoryList.add("Category 5");
        categoryList.add("Category 6");

        elementList.add("element 1");
        elementList.add("element 2");
        elementList.add("element 3");
        elementList.add("element 4");

        categorySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        elementSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        // create adapter for category and elementList
        ArrayAdapter<String> categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categoryList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> elementAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elementList);

        categorySpinner.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
        elementSpinner.setAdapter(elementAdapter);


        // when user select any category
        categorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int categoryIndex, long l) {
                if (categoryIndex >= elementList.size())
                    elementSpinner.setSelection(elementList.size() - 1);
                else
                    elementSpinner.setSelection(categoryIndex);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Your question was how to change element value of spinner when category change and element value set to max if element size is greater than category list size. Its work for this condition. If your question is not this then please make your question clear and add some code you have used.